# Special Characters Shown as Html Code and Asp Post breaks

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex, model-view-controller

Hello guys sometimes from user i get string like: N106 ORG ,,test''(09090909)

in code behind i assign this value to textbox with javascript

like:

```
$("#Address1").val('@(Model.AddressLineOne)');
```

(@Model.AddressLineOne is the users input address as i mentioned above)

if user input start with ,, and has no ending  it shows like

N106 ORG ,,test'&#39(09090909) so after,, character "" shown as &#39&#39.

Asp gives error on Save

> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Address="...  N106 ORG ,,test&#39&#39(09090909).

can you suggest what to do with this characters? p.s alsow i dont want [Allow Html] tag in asp ! i dont need  '&#39 in field and database!

Answer (score 0):

You should encode such inputs before processing. refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I managed problem, model must be placed like "Model.addressline" not '@Model.addresslin'e when assigned to textbox val in JavaScript.double quots helped!